# eCom website(Bootstrap UI and JS libraries) accessed on a BS hosted mobile device tested by Selenium script is failing at random element each time

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, asynchronous

The client runs a eCommerce web site developed with BootStrap UI framework and  backed by SAP. This desktop website is used not only on desktop but also with mobile devices. In order to test the mobile version, the client is using BrowserStack cloud platform.

The Selenium-Java Script developed is failing(`Element not clickable, Element not found, Element not accessible etc`) randomly at a different element each time.

I have incorporated fluent waits(up to 50 sec) at each element, but still the same result.

**I am aware that SAP commerce cloud website using BootStrap UI framework(v3.4.0) is inherently asynchronous at run time, while Selenium-Java script is synchronous. Technically fluent waits are supposed to take care of this mis-match, but it was not.**

We are using Selenium v4.16 and JDK 21.

Does any one were in this situation and how did you resolve this? Basically we are having no clue what is happening and why !

Comment: Your site might be loading the elements dynamically. 
Try using perhaps a different locator in Selenium that would be loading with a static value.

Answer (score 0):

**@grandEL-dsouza**

Thanks for your reply.
Later to the posting, I have observed that in most of the cases, the run time is not able to execute just one button click next to an input box. I could retrieve the text on the button, but could not be able to click on it.

So, after many ways of writing Selenium locators, I finally went to **JavaScript executor interface**, which did work !! So once crossed that road block, the rest is keeping more amount of wait times in the form of fluent waits with conditional ExpectedConditions clause. All the elements are accessible with little or no problem.

**Lesson learnt**: When you are testing website made out of the javaScript based libraries, try the conditional fluent waits with ExpectedConditions and finally don't forget to use JavaScript executor interface for your click actions.